# The use of the verb "predict" in the simple present tense with a verb in the past simple tense

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/itpLU7OzNV8). It is at the beginning.

> The Big Bang Theory **predicts** that all matter, time and space **began** in an incredibly tiny, compact state about 14 billion years ago.

I am confused because as dictionaries say *predict* used to say that an event or action will happen in the future, especially as a result of knowledge or experience. How can someone predict the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Predict*** takes on different meaning and nuance in science. When we have a scientific *model*, that is a theoretical description of a system, like quantum mechanics or particle physics, what that model tells us is called a *prediction*. Much of the time it's predicting the result of some experiment or situation, so it has much the same meaning as the everyday usage. However, it is still used when the model is intended to tell us what may have happened in the past, which happens quite a lot in cosmology.